# Does running git switch --orphan lib switch me to the lib branch?

Tags: git, macos

If I understand correctly running the following should create an empty orphaned `lib` branch.

```
% git switch --orphan lib
Switched to a new branch 'lib'
```

And git seems to indicate that it has now switched to the `lib` branch.

However if I run:

```
% git branch
  master
```

It seems to indicate that I'm on `master` still.

How do I know which branch I'm on?

Also if I try to switch to the `lib` branch, this is the message.

```
git checkout lib
error: pathspec 'lib' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

So it seems the `lib` branch was never created ...

### Update

Someone says it works in one of the answers, so I updated git to the latest version on MacOS.

```
git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
```

And I've repeated the entire experiment starting from scratch and these are all the steps.

```
 % mkdir dir
 % cd dir
 % touch file
 % cd ..
 % git add *
 % git commit -m "First Commit"
[main (root-commit) 3060034] First Commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dir/file
% git switch --orphan lib
Switched to a new branch 'lib'
 % git branch
  main
```

### Answer Comment

OK got it now.  We have to actually do a commit on the new branch in order for `git branch` to show that we are on the branch...

So this is what I did.

```
 % touch file
 % git add * && git commit -m "Lib Commit"
[lib (root-commit) de7b684] Lib Commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dir/file
 % git branch
* lib
  main
```

Comment: Interesting.... perhaps you hit a bug? If you were on `master`, you would  see an asterisk besides it.

Comment: Hmmm ... Perhaps its a bug ... this is the version of git I'm on ... 
`git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)`

Comment: Just checked and `git checkout --orphan` does the same thing... at least you know it's not a `git switch`-only thing.

Comment: Not completely sure if this is _really_ the way to go _but_ it seems like `.git/HEAD` can tell you where you are regardless.

Comment: The result of that command is *very* similar to the state of a newly created repo with `git init`. `.git/HEAD` will point to the `lib` branch, but the `lib` branch doesn't exist (in sofar as there is no file named `refs/heads/lib`). Only once you commit on that new branch does it really "exist". That's because there's no commit that `refs/heads/lib` could possibly reference in that state (a branch must always point to a commit).

Comment: OH - OK - GOT IT!!  Cool!!  After I did a commit on the new branch the new branch shows up!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things work as intended. In particular, if you ask for the status

```
$ git status
On branch lib

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

you see that you are about to start with a clean slate, most importantly, there are no commits, yet.

Comment: For me .. And perhaps it is because I'm on MacOS ... It did not say I was on the `lib` branch until I made a commit on that branch.